# Submitting data to a web portal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to access a website with python and I'm having some trouble using the requests and mechanize modules. Basically the way I do this task manually is that I load the website portal and log on then click a button and fill out a form and submit this to receive a download. I've gotten to the log on stage and am having trouble submitting my username and log in am currently using this method

```
import requests
payload = {"username":"user","password":"pass"}
r = requests.post("portal login address",data=payload)
response = r.content
print(response)
```

but this gives me the exact same output as a get request where I don't include the payload. I am also wondering how I can simulate these button clicks and form submissions, I know mechanize can be used but I'm unclear as to how

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mechanize module, in this way:

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open("<page>")

# you can access the form by name or some other means
# ive used a loop here just as an example
for form in br.forms():
    form["username"] = "saurabhav"
    form["password"] = "8558881858"
    form.submit()
```

Have a look at [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: I tried this but it can't find the field username. I guess this means I've named it wrong how do  go about finding the correct name to use?